# Find highest difference between two rows

Tags: mysql, rows, max

I have a table that stores values each hour from a website based on 100 users. Each user is there each hour, but might have a higher/lower value.

I want to find the highest difference between the rows and output them.

```
mysql_query("SELECT `username`,`energy` FROM `hoflevel`");
```

I know I could loop through all the rows of each user and find the highest value, but that is too much code. I'm sure there is a way to figure out the biggest difference between two rows, grouped by the username. It doesn't have to be only each hour. It would be like a "**Alan set the record of 345,048 Energy at 5am yesterday!**".

Comment: So it's definitely a difference that you want? Sort of a `SELECT username, max(energy1-energy2) FROM hoflevel GROUP BY username`, where `energy1` and `energy2` are all pairs of `energy` for that `username`? And what if a given user only has one value of `energy` in the database so far?

Comment: Right. Energy1 - energy2. Forget the only one value thing. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gets the maximum difference in `energy` per user, ignoring users with only a single record:

```
SELECT hoflevel.username, MAX(hoflevel.energy-h.energy) as maxDiff 
FROM hoflevel 
LEFT JOIN hoflevel h 
ON h.username=hoflevel.username AND hoflevel.energy>=h.energy
WHERE h.energy IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY hoflevel.username;
```

Basically, it joins `hoflevel` to itself on `username` which produces a table with `username` and every pair of `energy` values for that user.

Then it works out the maximum difference between energies grouped by `username`.

Note, you could further save some computation by ignoring users who may have multiple records in the database but the same `energy` each time (and so their `maxDiff` is 0) by changing the `>=` to a `>` in the join condition.